# Can I have a different email address to confirm a group subscription?

Tags: webform-civicrm, email, subscribe

I'm using a webform to allow users to sign up to a newsletter group.  The confirmation emails use the default 'from' email address in Civi. Is there a way to select a different email address for this confirmation? Civi is at 4.7.27 and Drupal, of course.

Comment: Are the confirmation emails coming from webform or civicrm?

Comment: It's using a webform with 'Confirm Subscriptions' checked on the 'Additional Options' page.  I guess the emails come from Civi and are using the default 'from' email address.